# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/oss/driver/internal/core/util/collection/SimpleQueryPlan while running apache-spark connector springboot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm attempting to run an Apache-Spark query in Spring Boot to retrieve data from Cassandra, however the following problem keeps popping up on my terminal.

Note: Connection is successful to cassandra.

- Spring Boot version: 2.7.4
- java version : 8
- spark version: 3.2.0

This exception can be found at "result1.show()" in the service file below.

Check out my code here:

```
// my service 
@Override
    public byte[] getAllDataSpark() {
        
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName(sparkAppName)
                .master(sparkMaster)
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host" ,"10.1.7.43" )
                .config("spark.executor.instances" ,"4" )
                .config("spark.executor.memory" ,"10G" )
                .config("spark.driver.memory","5G")
                .config("spark.cassandra.read.timeoutMS" ,"1200000")
                .getOrCreate();
        
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
                 .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                 .option("keyspace", "datacrowd")
                 .option("table", "loc_location_main_data")
                 .load();
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("viewTable");
        
        Dataset<Row> result = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM viewTable LIMIT 10");

        Dataset<Object> result1 = result.as(Encoders.bean(Object.class));
        
        result1.show();

        return result1.toString().getBytes();
    }
```

// my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.valoores.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-spark</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cassandra-spark</name>
    <description>datacrowd-cassandra</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <!-- <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> -->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spark and Cassandra dependencies -->

    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-driver_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency
        >
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>

</project>
```

I have attempted to add the following dependencies based on my research:

```
  <dependency>
          <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
          <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
          <artifactId>java-driver-query-builder</artifactId>
          <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
                 <dependency>
          <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
          <artifactId>java-driver-core-shaded</artifactId>
          <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
          <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-runtime</artifactId>
          <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and I've tried several versions, but the problem persists.

Comment: note that in my note mentioned in the top of the page i have spring boot version : 2.7.4 and not spark sorry for my mistake

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you using here? Please see examples [here](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/SparkBuildExamples) and also the compatible Spark Cassandra Connector (SCC) version [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility) to match up with your Spark, Scala and Cassandra versions.

Comment: version cassandra is  4.0.6 ,i have update the spark version to  3.3.0 and same error persist

Comment: Spark server version & Scala versions are still missing.

Answer (score 0):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` usually indicates that there's a conflict with the dependencies in your project.

[Spring Boot 2.7.4 uses Cassandra Java driver 4.14.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.4/reference/html/dependency-versions.html). On the other hand, [Spark Cassandra connector uses Cassandra Java driver 4.13.0](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v3.2.0/project/Versions.scala#L8).

But to be honest, it's hard to know what the problem is because you didn't provide the full error message and the full stack trace. Additionally, it's important to include a minimal code sample that replicates the problem. Cheers!